# Best approach to select particlular cell value for data extarction is XPATH?

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, selector

Hi I am working a huge set of data tables and I am trying to optimized to grab the value form those tables.

There are many ways to select element. What is the best approach to grab particular cell value from the tabular data. For example, the page https://mytestbasics.blogspot.com/2022/11/sample-page.html there is a tablular data. if we want to select the code value data what will be the best approach?
[Picture to grab data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGSlN.png)

I am trying to find the best approach for selecting data so that the process will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best approach will be to do this with other tools, not Selenium since Selenium need to actually access each UI element. So, tools like Beautifulsoup will do that much faster.
But if you still want to use Selenium CSS Selectors will be slightly faster than other locators.